# Unable to access salesforce discussion boards

Tags: community

Am able to login to salesforce discussion boards but that page is displaying error "You are not allowed to access this site ". What is this error. This is happening only in office pcs. but am accessing from my laptop at home.

Comment: Looks like it should be the firewall on your office which might be blocking it.. Why need boards when you have salesforce.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: I have discussed regarding this with Network admin. he is also unable to resolve this. @prady I have team of 4 fresher developers. They are trying to access it :)

Comment: Usually I can just refresh the page when this happens.. but you've probably tried that.

Comment: @VictorKilo Yes, this is happening for all developers in my office..

Comment: Do the office computers have any cookie filtering or anything of that sort? Does it occur in every browser type?

Comment: Yes, this is occurring in all browsers..

Answer (score 1):

Try logging in using the secure site http://boards.developerforce.com/ and see if it resolves the issue. Also ensure you are allowing cookies on your browser.

Comment: Same error am getting "We're sorry, but you have been banned from using this site. "

Comment: mmm.. Did any of you guys tried to do some mischief with the boards site... I cant see anything else other than a firewall in your office blocking it or salesforce decided to block your ip

Comment: @Reddy Either your username or your IP has been banned by some moderator. What's you username?

Comment: Salesforce has banned our company IP range,because our HR team posted some marketing related posts. Now we are able to access discussion boards.